# Dynamically incrementing number of rows after already initializing my 2d matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a question that doesnt seem to be answered on this website or others, Im fairly new to these things, so here is my first question on a website. I want to add lines to my 2d array, Everytime the user inputs chars 'a' 'l' (add line) he will then input after these two chars, numbers. (this being done several times) Which means that the length of rows are increasing after every time the user inputs  'al'. how do i initialze a matrix that i dont know how many rows it might have? and then within the compiling time add rows

My question is how do i alter the length of rows once i have already initialized it to a specific length, or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data structure `vector`, which allows dynamically changing its size when required. Here is a simple example where a new line is added to an existing two-dimensional array with vector's `push_back` method. You can read more about vector [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}; // Initializes a 2x3 array

    vec.push_back({7, 8, 9}); // Adds a new line to the array

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << vec[i][j];
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could dynamically allocate memory for your array, but this comes with several drawbacks. C++ arrays are fixed sizes, and the only way to resize them is to make a new array, copy the old one into it, delete the old one and continue with your work. This can get messy really fast and I'd advise against it. Continuous copying and memory allocation are quite tasking operations. If you absolutely must avoid using vectors, then I would suggest declaring an array big enough to hold all the rows your user can add and then just have a counter that marks the current number of rows used. Here's a quick example how to declare a dynamic two-dimensional array.

```
int main()
{
    int m = 2; // Number of rows
    int n = 3; // Number of columns

    int **arr = new int*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[n];
    }

    // Continue with your work

    return 0;
}
```

More importantly, everything allocated with `new` must be deallocated with `delete`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) // Memory cleanup
{
    delete arr[i];
}

delete[] arr;
```

Comment: thank you ! i will read into the vectors, but is there a way to do it through only pointers, and not using vectors?

Comment: No, not directly. There are workarounds, but they're somewhat chaotic. I've edited an example on how to do it with pointers, but I'd still strongly suggest usage of vectors.